# What is the effect of screen scale (in Windows) on web components?

Tags: responsive, scale

I have a question regarding the screen scale issue in Windows.
We are dealing with a screen scale issue that affects the visibility of the components in our application. It causes a zoom-in, mainly on laptops, which adds scrolling without intention, and hides CTA buttons beneath it. Our application are not responsive.

My questions are:

1. Is it possible to predict how the screen scale will affect the components in our app?
2. Is there a way to know how many users will be affected by the screen scale if it happens on laptops?

We would appreciate any information you can provide on this issue.

Thank you,
Liron

Answer (score 1):

1. In order to predict how screen scale will affect components in your app, you can use any virtualized device and environment emulator (e.g. [Sauce Labs](https://saucelabs.com/) or [Mabl](https://www.mabl.com/))
2. Your best bet is to review any analytics you have access to (e.g. Google Analytics, Matomo, Pendo, MixPanel); most capture visitor OS and screen resolution as a basic capability. That will allow you to see how many users are on Windows and have a screen resolution R (R < X), to give you a good sense of the potential percentage of users impacted.